# How do test for an alternating row in DataBound

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This code inserts a row under the first row that i choose to edit but when i edit the second row now new row appears can someone tell me or show me how to correct this. I've tried doing e.Row.RowInex + 1 and i get no rows. but if i do e.Row.RowInex + 2 i get a new row for the first but not the second.

```
    protected void PageSettings_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0))
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex + 2, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        row.Cells.AddRange(CreateCells());

        Table table = e.Row.Parent as Table;
        table.Rows.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + 2, row);

    }
}

private TableCell[] CreateCells()
{
    TableCell[] cells = new TableCell[2];

    TableCell cell;

    cell = new TableCell();
    cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
    cells[0] = cell;

    cell = new TableCell();
    cell.ColumnSpan = 4;
    cells[1] = cell;

    return cells;

}
```

Solved for any one who has this trouble

```
((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a response to your title question: 'How do test for an alternating row in DataBound':

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
        {
            // alternate rows
        }
    }
}
```